# Expand Notifications Panel Programmatically Android

Tags: android, statusbar

I'm creating an android application that has a gesture to expand the status bar.. I used the following code to expand it.. :

```
            try {
                Object sbservice = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                Method showsb;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
                } else {
                    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
                }

                showsb.invoke(sbservice);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I tried this on an emulator and it worked.. But when I tried on a real device this throws an exception

> SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to
>   run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires
>   android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Any Idea ?

Comment: Could you solve this problem ? If solved, please share your solution with us.

Answer (score 0):

`android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL` is a signature level permission. Your app will not be able to use it until and unless it has the same signature as the system.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add permission in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```